# What is this bean called?

Tags: food-identification

Please identify these. The beans are very large as you can see in relation to the iphone.
[image]

Inside:
[image]

Comment: Can you open one for us?

Comment: Please use with caution! Some people may be allergic to broad beans, which can lead to serious symptoms - even death. People shouldn't consume them if they had never consumed any in the past.

Comment: While you're right that trying fava beans for the first time can be dangerous, the danger isn't an allergy, it's G6PDD, otherwise known as "favism".  It affects about 1 out of 40 people, so relatively common, *especially* among folks of sub-saharan African descent.

Comment: Info: https://www.medicinenet.com/g6pd_deficiency/article.htm#glucose-6-phosphate_dehydrogenase_deficiency_facts

Answer (score 6):

They look a lot like fava beans (also commonly known as broad beans).

[This link](http://www.westoftheloop.com/2014/07/15/farmers-market-find-fava-beans/) has some images to compare to.

Comment: Fava beans are also known as broad beans in many commonwealth countries.

Comment: Best enjoyed with a nice Chianti....

Comment: Those are definitely fava beans.